# TL-WR841N router- bad signal and speed

Tags: wireless-router

I have bought some time ago a TP-link TL-WR841N v.8 and it worked ok. After i moved in into another apartment i had experiencing some bad signal and speed issues. I have the same internet provider and the speed they provide is 300 Mbps. The speed issues may be from their side, but the signal issues i have never experienced before and doesn't have anything to do with the internet.

I placed the router in the hall that connects all rooms and still having issues. I thought it may be from the interfering with other routers and i tried to change channels but the same. A router that is not in my house has better signal than mine. I measured the signal is about -60 the other router has -50. After i switched back to auto, the download speed boosted from 2MB/s to 7MB/s, but still having troubles with lagging and low signal some times.

I wonder if the placement is wrong or i should flash it with DD-WRT or something else. The signal varies from full signal on a laptop to about 3-4/5 lines, the issue is not constant. I also experience this when is only one device connected.

Sorry for the long story but i wanted to give all the available data.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem like you but before i tell you, i must ask you if you are on laptop and you are using its Wi-Fi or you got Wireless USB adapter, if you are using adapter, its placement could be the problem, otherwise if its not this check if other people are connected to it, another solution it might sound crazy but lots of appliances might interfere with the signal(personally this was my problem here) so check if you have some new electrical appliances.

Comment: i have usual appliances a tv a fridge nothing out of the ordinary. The issue appears on several laptops and also on phones even if is connected only 1 device.(i checked if someone hacked the wifi, but only the one i had are connected). Also on phone only 2-3 meters away the signal goes from 1 line to 4 and back to 1 and back to 5. I use the incorporated wifi. I also updated the firmware to latest version. My guess is that i have another wifi in range that has a lot of signal and maybe it's overwhelming this one.

Comment: It is possible and most likely, if your router is lower than 5ghz that means that other signals might interfere, i suggest if channel 1 is free you should use it. You would need a router and a USB wireless adapter that are both dual band, but it would be your best solution other than an Ethernet cable.

Comment: Ok thanks i will try keeping it on channel 1 and see if this works. I hope it will because i really think the other 5GHz wifi is overwhelming mine. I have 2.4 GHz. On the old apartment i had full signal all the time and the rest of the wifi's were at about 40-50% of signal. The 5GHz uses 5+10. I tried with channel 9, but didn't worked, i'll try this one.

Comment: Ok if its not working tell me i can think of different way